# Do the edge lengths in Networkx's draw() function have any significance?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, network-analysis

I have a couple of NetworkX graphs that have similar structures but vastly different edge lengths. 
First image:
[image]
Second Image:
[image]

Note that they both have clusters of 4 nodes that have very different edge lengths. Is this just a random occurrence or is there something significant to it? Note that red edges are pages, blue edges are students, and the edges represent views (If there is an edge between the nodes, that means the student viewed that page). Edges also have the number of views (frequency) encoded within them (Black is less than 5 views, Blue is more than 5 views)

Comment: Show some code you used. But for general usage of layout-algorithms: be very very careful interpreting those (better: don't do it; probably all based on heuristic over non-convex models; imagine a graph not satisfying euclidean-metric and it's embedding into 2d-space; ill-conditioned problem -> all solutions are somewhat failing but tuned for human-perception).

Comment: In the general case I would say no, the edgelength have no significance. But that may also depend on the actual algorithm in use. Judging from the picture there is not way one could possibly tell. Be reminded that this is a Q&A site about programming. See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

There is no well-defined interpretation of the length of the edges.

The networkx default uses `spring_layout`.  This attempts to find an arrangement which has closely connected nodes close together.  It does this by effectively treating the nodes as repelling objects and the edges as springs.  It starts with the nodes in random locations and then lets them move around according to these assumptions.